# How could a PHP value contain a string of zero length not equal to the empty string or null?

Tags: php, string, null, strlen

I am retrieving some data from an in-house store and in case of failure, I get a very specific response.  Calling `strlen()` on this variable returns the value of zero.  It is also not equal to NULL or "".  I'm using this code to test:

```
if ($data === NULL)
{
    echo("data was null\n");
}
else if ($data === "")
{
    echo("data was empty string\n");
}
else if (strlen($data) == 0)
{
    echo("data was length zero\n");
}
```

This result is outputting `data was length zero`.  What could the variable contain that is zero length, not null, and not the empty string?

Comment: What happens when you echo $data?

Comment: `var_dump($data);` to the rescue. So... what is it? *It's A Bird! It's A Plane! ... No, it's Just Lancelot.*

Comment: `else if ($data == "")` i think three equal signs matches type not strings

Comment: like gunr said..`$data` is probably not of type `string`

Comment: `false` would fit the bill.

Comment: look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) tables. it should answer the question.

Comment: I have certainly not used `var_dump()` as much as I should... thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returned value must be false then.

```
 echo strlen(false); // outputs 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not being an answer. I can only answer if you present a `var_dump($data);` But I think also suprising for me is this:

```
$data = "\0";

if ($data === NULL)
{
    echo("data was null\n");
}
else if ($data === "")
{
    echo "data was empty string\n";
}
else if (strlen($data) == 0)
{
    echo "data was length zero\n";
} 
else 
{
    echo "something strange happened\n";
}
```

Output: `something strange happened`

:)

Comment: An ASCII NULL character in a string is not the same as a [NULL datatype](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php).

Comment: **Beauty of PHP's binary strings.** `\0` has `strlen()` of 1... *EPIC!* PHP does not have strings but byte arrays. You can stick anything in them and `\0` has no effect on it :) `strlen` is more like `count`.

Comment: @MarkBaker I know that but I expected a strlen of zero. Thx CodeAngry!!! Of course you are right, we are not in C!! sorry I was totally wrong.... will delete the post as soon as you both read my comment

Comment: @hek2mgl You could leave it here so others can read my comment in case they come from a C/C++ background like me :) I very much hate dynamic typed languages where anything is anything else.

Comment: @CodeAngry About dynamically typed languages. I don't hate them but I'm with you, loose typing makes more problems than it brings benefits

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    $data = false;
```

I'm not sure why false has a strlen, but it does.

Comment: $data = 0; Does not give the same result, though.

Comment: It has a `strlen` for the same reason that you can add two strings (`"aa" + "bb"`) or that you can `str_replace(0, null, false)`: values are automatically converted to whatever type their consumer wants. It's another matter that the result might not be meaningful.